# Google apps script not iterating through all files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

The following script is meant to iterate through all files in a folder and 1) get the file name, 2) make a string modification of that name, 3) use that modified string to retrieve the id of an existing file. My script does all of this, except it only iterates through the first file in my search folder. I double-checked that I have multiple files in the search folder. I'm probably missing something simple. ...

```
function listMsForTmp() {
// define search folder
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myID");           
  var value = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();                                                   
  var searchFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(value);                                              
  var files = searchFolder.getFiles();
// Make containers
  var names = []
  var ids = []

  while( files.hasNext()){
// get tmp file ID
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(files.next().getId()); 
// get tmp file name                                       
    var newName = file.getName().replace("template","master"); 
// get ms ID based on tmp file                                 
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(newName); 
// name vars for ms file, id and name                                               
    var file = files.next();
    var id = file.getId();
    var name = file.getName();
// store vars
    names.push(name)                                      
    ids.push(id)

      }

  Logger.log(ids)
  Logger.log(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function listMsForTmp() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("myID");           
  var sh=ss.getSheets()[0];//the left most sheet is the default if you don't choose one
  var value = sh.getRange("A1").getValue();                                                   
  var searchFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(value);                                              
  var files=searchFolder.getFiles();
  var names = [];
  var ids = [];
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file=files.next(); 
    var newName=file.getName().replace("template","master"); 
    ids.push(file.getId());
    names.push(file.getName());
  }

  Logger.log(ids)
  Logger.log(names)
}
```